# SVG in object problems with click event inside JS

Tags: javascript, html, object, svg

i have an svg image inside object element of HTML document.

```
<object id="svg1" data="nejc/bg.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
Your browser doesn't support SVG
</object>
```

And i have javascript code. Inside of it i added click event which execute when svg is done loading. Code look for id in .svg file which i added on groups of elements. Everything is working. But i am having problem now and then when i load page the svg elements cant be clicked, but if i refresh it then the click is working just fine.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    //button where are you
    var a = document.getElementById("svg1");

    //it's important to add an load event listener to the object, as it will load the svg doc asynchronously
    a.addEventListener("load",function(){
        var svgDoc = a.contentDocument; //get the inner DOM of svg
        var delta = svgDoc.getElementById("right"); //get the inner element by id
        delta.addEventListener("click",function(){
                this.style.fill = '#DC7827';
                 setTimeout("document.location.href = '_mobile_whereareyou.php';",200);

        },false);    //add behaviour
    },false);

    //button place ID
    var b = document.getElementById("svg1");

    //it's important to add an load event listener to the object, as it will load the svg doc asynchronously
    b.addEventListener("load",function(){
        var svgDocB = b.contentDocument; //get the inner DOM of svg
        var beta = svgDocB.getElementById("left"); //get the inner element by id
        beta.addEventListener("click",function(){
                this.style.fill = '#DC7827';
                setTimeout("document.location.href = '_mobile_placeID.php';",200);

        },false);    //add behaviour
    },false);

  });
```

I am guessing that when svg elements could not be clicked then the svg image did not load correctly. Is there any way how to make sure that svg element is loaded and click is working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I came to solution. I was thinking right  that svg did not load properly when click was not working. So i wrape all code in below block.

```
$('#svg1').load('nejc/bg.svg', null, function() { 
//here is now my code given in question
});
```

This function load svg and on complete executes code in funtion.